# Java FX in Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: eclipse, macos, javafx

Since I had problems with compiling JavaFX Code from Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.7 using java development kit 1.7.0_04 i just want to share my intermediate solution with interested people:

Problem:

- The jfxrt.jar and other .jar files are not recognized when selecting the new jdk issued by oracle as a new jre/jdk in eclipse.
- The jdk is installed within /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk which is recognized as a package.
- Adding the path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar later is not possible since the file open dialog of eclipse does not allow to navigate to the inside of the package

Solution:
Create a symbolic link from outside the package to inside the package and follow the link within the file open dialog.

Simply go to a terminal and execute the following:

[0-/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines]:sudo ln -s 1.7.0.jdk/Contents/ 1.7.0.jdk_Contents

This creates the symbolic link 1.7.0.jdk_Contents using super user permissions (sudo).

By this compilation and execution of JavaFx code works fine and as expected.

Comment: bit of a hack, but it worked for me

Comment: a little update, the new Eclipse (4.2) still does not recognise the `jfxrt.jar`, but it does not have the navigate issue. So you can add the file manually, without the symbolic linking.

Answer (score 2):

It's not need to do all said before, just use a allmost unknown behaviour of Finder dialogs: Drag & Drop.
You can open a Finder window from console with:

```
open /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib
```

so yo will see jfxrt.jar and other .jar files. Drag this files to Eclipse's Add external jar dialog window... et voila!
Dependencies satisfaced! No link needed!

Answer (score 0):

The initial JavaFX 2.1 release in jdk1.7.0_u4 was not supported by e(fx)clipse.
This [support thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/efxclipse/JMiJKBjqxeo) indicates that the maintainer of the plugin is aware of the incompatibility issue is pushing a patch to the plugin repository to fix the issue and in the meantime recommends using a JavaFX 2.2 preview build instead.